# how do I set my icon grid to a better shape?

Tags: lubuntu, icons, desktop-icons

I'm running a Lubuntu 14.04 in my computer.

I wanna use auto-arrange the icons in the desktop but the columns in wich they arrange have too wide horizontal separation.

Is there some parameter to change this?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote `iconic` to solve this problem by letting you define grid dimensions for your icons. Additionally it will:

- Allow you to move icons to any of three monitors
- Not suffer the "lost icon syndrome" that occurs when monitors of multiple resolutions are used
- Sort icons alphabetically, alphabetically with "Link to" prefix ignored, sort by modified date ascending or date descending
- Allow different grid size (columns x rows) depending on monitor, EG more on 4K monitor than 2K monitor
- Instant **Test** button for quick experimentation on column x row changes or reserved space changes for monitor left, top, right or bottom areas
- **Test** button will last for x seconds defined by you, clear all windows before test and restore them after test
- Bash script for easy modifications

You can get the script on [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic).

Here's the main screen:

[image: iconic main menu.png]

Visit the [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic) page for **iconic** to see all the other screens, explanations and a copy of the script.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll try it soon